# Alamofire 4 network stream closed

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to make a POST request using latest Alamofire 4.0.0 / Swift 3 passing JSON in the request.

The request calls a wildfly  server and takes up to a minute to return with data.

However, I constantly get a server error java.io.IOException: UT010029: Stream is closed.

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Connection": "Keep-Alive"

]
Alamofire.request("myUrl", method: .post,  parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
     .validate().responseJSON { response in
        print("Response")
        print(response)
        }
    }
```

Alamofire doesn't complain at all and doesn't log anything.

I have tried other requests to the same server/service that return instantly and I get into the completion handler. 
Is this just a timeout issue? If so how can I adjust it?

Comment: Have you figured out what is happening? I'm seeing something similar with the delay.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a very similar problem with GET requests. Turns out I was passing an empty dictionary `[:]` as parameters to the request method. Omitting the `parameters:` completely in the call solved the issue.